# Can I execute array methods in angular 2+ template

Tags: arrays, angular

I'm trying this code:

`<p>{{ items.map(x => x.name).join() }}</p>`

But I have `Template parse error` here.

So, I want to extract just one property from object like LINQ `.Select()` in C# and concatenate that to single comma separated string.

Can I do something like that? What ways to resolve it? Only move logic to `.ts` file?

Comment: prob is in AOT code or even in the debug JIT ?

Comment: it is debug JIT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot execute such functions in your HTML, **and you should not do it**;

Instead, change it to your TS part and bind it to a function:

```
betweenPfunction() {
 return this.items.map(x => return x.name).join()
}
```

---

```
<p>{{ betweenPfunction() }}</p>
```

Comment: Even better: Calculate the value once and store it (for example in a derived array). Otherwise this method is executed every time the view renders for every item.

Comment: @magnattic depends on how he did in his HTML, I did not see the whole snippet so that I can suggest a better solution , that was just so he understand the idea (logic) behind, and yes could be as u'd described.